# Strange behavior in plain text file in notepad?

Tags: formatting, notepad, newlines

I Just received the txt file, and it looks good like this,

[image]

But when I pasted it in my cisco device it did't load properly ,
First I did't get it because text looks okay, then for just curiosity, 
 I copied the text and pasted in Micrsoft excel there i can see some new lines
in there .

[image]

Then i copied the text and pasted in new notepad file and when i hit saveas and save it , it suddenly changes to this

[image]

I tried removing and applying word-wrap but it did't work,

So finally I converted txt to .py file then I was able to see the new lines and then wrote the script to remove new lines there and again converte from .py to .txt.

But what is happening to the text i received ? why i am not seeing the new lines in text but able to see in excel and in .py mode.

**EDIT1**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf8lcvtiqx76g2p/abcd.zip?dl=0[link to zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf8lcvtiqx76g2p/abcd.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Notepad is not a suitable text editor for just about anything. Get something that understands different types of line breaks, like Notepad++. Also, please provide the file in question. Preferably in a a ZIP archive or whatever to make sure nothing changes the content.

Comment: @DanielB I provided the link to dropbox

Answer (score 1):

You have probably encountered a line break issue. Historically, three major line break types were used:

- Line Feed (LF), ASCII code 0x10 - used by Unix-like systems
- Carriage Return (CR), ASCII code 0x13 - used by old Mac OS versions
- CR+LF (two characters) - used by Windows

Modern Apple OSes use LF line breaks.

Notepad's line break support is very limited. It doesn't deal properly with anything except CR+LF. You can check which type of line breaks is used in your file by inspecting it in a hex editor (eg. XVI32) or using a proper text editor, like Sublime Text, Notepad++ or Atom.